# How can I select or highlight a block in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, selection, highlight

I want to select or highlight a block in Emacs without using the mouse, but doing it from the keyboard like Vim's visual mode. What is the easiest way to do this from a keyboard?

Comment: See the article: ["Working with rectangular selections"](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2008/12/working-with-rectangular-selections.html), especially the comments section. See also the section of [CUA mode documentation](http://www.cua.dk/cua.html) titled "CUA rectangle support". There's also a [nice video on Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/1168225).

Comment: C-M-h `mark-defun`

Comment: You can also use Spacemacs to get the vim keybinds inside emacs.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Take a look at region-rectangle in Emacs.

In short, you start selection like usual with <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>, then kill region with <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> and paste (or *yank*) killed block with <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd>.

Comment: That doesn't kill regions, it kills rectangles, which is a lot different from what vim's visual mode does, in my experience.

Answer (score 89):

If I understand the question correctly, it is not about rectangular regions originally.

**`C-Spc`** puts a mark at the current position.

Wherever your cursor is afterwards, the text between the last mark and the current position is "selected" (you can highlight this by activating `transient-mark-mode`, but this will also mean that marks have to be deleted when you don't want highlight).

You can operate on that region with commands like:

**`C-w`** . . Kill region.  This deletes and puts the region into the kill ring.
**`C-y`** . . Yank.  This inserts the last snippet from the kill ring.
**`M-y`** . . Cycle kill ring.  Immediately after `C-y`, this replaces the yanked part by the other snippets in the kill ring.
**`M-w`** . . Save region into kill ring.  Like `C-w`, but doesn't delete.

This is just the basic usage.  Marks have other uses, too.  I recommend the tutorial (**`C-h t`**).

Comment: Worth noting that `C-s` `C-r` are commonly used in this context to go find the end/start of the region. (Especially useful in a macro.)

Comment: Well, it is very good commands, but... How to select the marked region? After all I am still need it, i.e. to indent the code between marks.

Comment: The region between the last mark and the current point (that is where your cursor is) _is_ the selected region.  Just run `M-x indent-region`.

Comment: @Svante No, it is not selected. Although the `indent-region` works just fine, but the `c-indent-line-or-region`(the one, that bound to the *tab* key) is not. The last function works not on the *marked* regions, but on the *selected* ones, i.e. the region that is highlighted like if you had selected it with mouse.

Comment: @YagamyLight Ah, you can do that by hitting `C-Spc` twice where you put the mark.  That activates transient-mark-mode temporarily (until you cancel (with `C-g`)).  Then move the point to see the selected region appear.

Answer (score 47):

Emacs 24.4 now has [rectangle-mark-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Rectangles). Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> to invoke it.

Comment: How do you move the rectangle block ?

Comment: This is correct, but no source cited...

Answer (score 16):

Although `C-SPC` is a common way to start marking something from
wherever your point is, there are often quicker/easier ways that don't
involve explicitly moving to start/end points...

### Built-in selection shortcuts

- **`M-h`** — an important means to *mark a paragraph*.  A "paragraph"
  often means a block of code.
- **`C-M-h`** and `C-M-@` — for *marking sexps and defuns*,
  respectively.  This works for several languages, not just lisps.
- **hold down shift** — another slick way to highlight during
  movement.  E.g., `M-S-f` selects forward a whole word.  This is
  **[`shift-select-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shift-Selection.html)**,
  and it is enabled by default in Emacs 24+.  On some (non-chiclet)
  keyboards, you should be able to hold down `C-S-` with a single
  pinky.

You can press any of these repeatedly to grow the selection.

There are also a few special ways to mark things:

- **`C-x h`** — *mark the whole buffer*
- **`C-x SPC`** — enter *rectangle mark mode*

<sub>*(NOTE: use `C-g` often to cancel marking while
experimenting.)*</sub>

### Add-ons

There are a few *add-on packages* that improve selecting regions and
things.  These are all play nicely together and fit different use
cases.  Use them all!

- **[expand-region](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el)**:
  Expand region increases the selected region by semantic units. Just
  keep pressing the key until it selects what you want.  `C-=` is a
  recommended binding for it.  Hit it a few times to get what you
  need.
- **[easy-kill](https://github.com/leoliu/easy-kill)**: Use `M-w` and
  a mnemonic to select different types of things, like words, sexps,
  lists, etc.
- **[zop-to-char](https://github.com/thierryvolpiatto/zop-to-char)**:
  Like *zap-to-char*, but provides nice selection and other
  menu-driven actions.
- **[diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl)**: Highlight uncommitted changed regions.  Use `diff-hl-mark-hunk` to select/mark a hunk.
- **[symbol-overlay](https://github.com/wolray/symbol-overlay)**: Select symbol at point with a keystroke (`M-i`).  Then you can do other things with it, like copy, search, jump, replace, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Use <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> to set a mark and move your cursor.

The `transient-mark-mode` will highlight selections for you. <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `transient-mark-mode`.

You can setup Emacs to enable this mode by default using a customization. <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `transient-mark-mode`.

Answer (score 2):

... and in case you are using [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> is not working for you: you need to clear the [Intelligent Input Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus) (IBus) "next input method" key binding, as in

> run `ibus-setup` and change the key binding for
> "next input method" to something else (or delete it entirely by
> clicking the "..." button and then the "Delete" button).

The quote is taken from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23458103/1587329) to a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

To expand answer of [Edin Salkovic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657672/how-can-i-select-or-highlight-a-block-in-emacs/657775#657775), if you use CUA mode, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to begin a visual block selection. There are plenty of shortcuts to control block selection described in the [documentation of CUA](http://www.cua.dk/cua.html).

Answer (score 0):

With Emacs 25, simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and then move your cursor wherever you want to highlight/select the region of text which interests you. After that, you may need these commands:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> for cutting.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> for copying.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> for pasting.