# By Emacs, how to join two lines into one?

Tags: emacs, editor

I am new to Emacs. I have googled this but no good answer there. One of them is 
Ctrl-n Ctrl-a Backspace
This works but is stupid. Is there a quick and simple way to join a block of lines into a single line?

Actually, I can use Esc-q to auto-fill a paragraph now, but how could I get it to revert without UNDO?

Comment: Thanks, for the idea, I'll bind it to <M-1>.

Comment: The command "undo" is usually bound to C-_ (control-underscore)...

Comment: Normally I do C-e C-d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a new command for this, temporarily adjusting the fill width before using the the  Esc-q command:

```
;; -- define a new command to join multiple lines together --
(defun join-lines () (interactive)
 (setq fill-column 100000)
 (fill-paragraph nil)
 (setq fill-column 78)
)
```

Obviously this only works, if your paragraph has less than 100000 characters.

Comment: Without clobbering fill-column, that would be
    (defun join-lines ()
      (interactive)
      (let ((fill-column 999999))
        (fill-paragraph nil)))

Comment: Yeah. This should be more graceful.

Comment: What about this ?

(defun unfill-paragraph ()
  "Does the opposite of fill-paragraph"
  (interactive)
  (let ((fill-column (point-max)))
    (fill-paragraph nil)))

Comment: Ray Vega's answer (below) should be the accepted one tbh.

Answer (score 199):

Place point anywhere on the ***last*** line of the group of lines that need joining and call

```
M-^
```

repeatedly until all the lines are merged.

Note: It leaves one space between all of the now joined lines.

Comment: What is M-^ usually bound to?

Comment: stsquad: you need to press Meta + Shift + 6 (Shift + 6 will give you ^)

Comment: Ah, the joys of day by day improving my Emacsfu. Only it can make me wonder about having different join lines functions: one with an extra space, one without it.

Comment: And if you want to join from the ***first*** line, it's (intuitively enough), `C-u M-^` (which tends to be a lot more useful imho).

Comment: In my setup ^ is used to compose characters like â and thus M-^ does not work.  And, on my German keyboard, ^ is not shift-6, also.  Is there a trick for me here (aside from defining a key binding of my own)?

Comment: @DirkHerrmann `M-^` on a german keyboard is best input as `ESC ^ SPC`

Comment: mark region and then issue M-^ to join multiple lines with space

Answer (score 40):

`M-x join-line` will join two lines.  Just bind it to a convenient keystroke.

Comment: Yes. It works. However, it is of no use to a block of several lines(3 lines or more). Any useful command for this purpose?

Comment: But if you go to the last line of the block and hit M-^ (the key binding for join-line) several times you will have the same effect. Goes pretty fast, so unless you have hundreds of lines to join I would prefer it over the fill-column hack. Otherwise do as Tal suggests, mark the block and replace newline (C-Q C-J) with nothing.

Comment: I have tried to bind join-line to M-1. It works fine also. As you you suggested, many solutions here for the purpose, so I'll try to use them all in a flexible way. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is exactly the same thing as pressing `M-^`, because `join-line` is aliased to `delete-indentation`, which is bound to `M-^`.

Comment: With my emacs version (29.0.50) this worked for more 2 lines. I highlighted all the lines then ran M-x join-line

Answer (score 12):

[Multiple Cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) combined with M-^ will collapse all selected lines into one with all extraneous white-space removed.

For example to select an entire buffer, invoke multiple cursors mode, collapse into one line, and then disable multiple cursors mode:

```
C-x h
M-x mc/edit-lines
M-^
C-g
```

Comment: My love for multiple cursors grows.

Comment: Thanks for the nice tip! works like magic.

Answer (score 11):

The Emacs conventional name for "join" is "fill".  Yes, you can join
*two* lines with `M-^` -- and that's handy -- but more generally you'll
want to join `n` lines.  For this, see the `fill*` commands, such as
`fill-region`, `fill-paragraph`, etc.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36631886/326516) for more info
on selecting things which can then be filled.

Also, you can join multiple lines with `M-^` by selecting those lines first. (Note that the universal argument does not work with this.)

Comment: Would vote this to be the idiomatically correct answer

Comment: `fill-region` worked well, but not `M-^` (nor `C-j` as a matter of fact) even when selecting the region first.

Comment: Also, not sure that fill=join. fill is join to a certain limit defined by `fill-width`.

Answer (score 9):

Just replace newlines with nothing.

Answer (score 5):

I like the way Sublime text Join line with Command J so I do it this way:

```
(defun join-lines (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (end-of-line)
  (delete-char 1)
  (delete-horizontal-space)
  (insert " "))
```

Comment: Nice, but how not to insert space when line below consisted only white spaces or was empty?

Answer (score 3):

I use the following function and bind it to 'M-J'.

```
(defun concat-lines ()
  (interactive)
  (next-line)
  (join-line)
  (delete-horizontal-space))
```

If you prefer to keep your cursor position, you can use [save-excursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21946623/elisp-saving-a-position-inserting-text-before-it-and-returning-to-the-same-lo).

Answer (score 2):

**The most simplest way ever:**

> 1. Select paragraph/lines by `M-h` or `C-SPC`
> 2. Press `M-q`
> 3. Witness the **Emagics (Emacs Magic)!!**

Answer (score 2):

Because `join-line` will left one space between two lines, also it only support join two lines. In case of you want to join plenty of lines without one space left, you can use "search-replace" mode to solve, as follows:

1. `C-%`
2. Query:  input `C-q C-j` `Enter`
3. Replace: `Enter`
4. Run the replacement. `Enter`

Done.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways come to mind:

1. Once you think of it, the most obvious (or at least easiest to remember) way is to use `M-q format-paragraph` with a long line length `C-x-f 1000`.
2. There is also a built-in tool `M-^ join-line`.  More usefully, if you select a region then it will combine them all into one line.

Answer (score 0):

"how could I get it to revert without UNDO?":

```
(defun toggle-fill-paragraph ()
  ;; Based on http://xahlee.org/emacs/modernization_fill-paragraph.html
  "Fill or unfill the current paragraph, depending upon the current line length.
When there is a text selection, act on the region.
See `fill-paragraph' and `fill-region'."
  (interactive)
  ;; We set a property 'currently-filled-p on this command's symbol
  ;; (i.e. on 'toggle-fill-paragraph), thus avoiding the need to
  ;; create a variable for remembering the current fill state.
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((deactivate-mark nil)
           (line-length (- (line-end-position) (line-beginning-position)))
           (currently-filled (if (eq last-command this-command)
                                 (get this-command 'currently-filled-p)
                               (< line-length fill-column)))
           (fill-column (if currently-filled
                            most-positive-fixnum
                          fill-column)))
      (if (region-active-p)
          (fill-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
        (fill-paragraph))
      (put this-command 'currently-filled-p (not currently-filled)))))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-q") 'toggle-fill-paragraph)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [EmacsWiki: Unfill Paragraph](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnfillParagraph)

```lisp
 ;;; Stefan Monnier <foo at acm.org>. It is the opposite of fill-paragraph    
    (defun unfill-paragraph (&optional region)
      "Takes a multi-line paragraph and makes it into a single line of text."
      (interactive (progn (barf-if-buffer-read-only) '(t)))
      (let ((fill-column (point-max))
            ;; This would override `fill-column' if it's an integer.
            (emacs-lisp-docstring-fill-column t))
        (fill-paragraph nil region)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic join of 2 lines:

```
(delete-indentation)
```

I like to line below to be joined to the current without moving the cursor:

```
("C-j" .
  (lambda (iPoint)
    "Join next line onto current line"
    (interactive "d")
    (next-line)
    (delete-indentation)
    (goto-char iPoint)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one behaves like in vscode. So it add space only if join line consisted something else than whitespace. And I bind it to `alt+shift+j`.

Shorter version based on [crux-top-join-line](https://github.com/bbatsov/crux/blob/20c07848049716a0e1aa2560e23b5f4149f2a74f/crux.el#L286):

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "M-J") (lambda () (interactive) (delete-indentation 1)))
```

Longer version based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/33005183/588759.

```lisp
;; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072662/by-emacs-how-to-join-two-lines-into-one/68685485#68685485
(defun join-lines ()
  (interactive)
  (next-line)
  (join-line)
  (delete-horizontal-space)
  (unless (looking-at-p "\n") (insert " ")))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-J") 'join-lines)
```