# How to select or highlight text without mouse

Tags: emacs, region

I am having a problem with selecting text. The method I used to use 
and which is suggested elsewhere no longer works for me. I want to select a (long) region, so it is time-consuming to use the mouse.

I set the mark at the beginning, with C-Space,
then go to the point at the end with C-S. But then the first mark has disappeared and the region is not highlighted.

This is the same method suggested elsewhere, and used to work for me
(unless I am forgetting something!)

[How to select or highlight a block in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657672/how-to-select-or-highlight-a-block-in-emacs)

Comment: When you C-space then move, the region **is** highlighted. It is basic emacs behavior and there no reason to malfunction. Maybe a matter of mode? Have you tried whith a fresh emacs session?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that the mark has been lost. More likely, you performed some action (sometimes scrolling can do this) that *deactivated* the region, that is, removed its highlighting. The region (the text between point and mark) is still present; it just isn't highlighted.

If this happens you can highlight the region again by using `C-x C-x`. That swaps point and mark, so if you want to keep the cursor at the same end of the region then just do it twice: `C-x C-x`.

Answer (score 2):

The highlighting depends on whether transient-mark-mode is active.  If it is not active, you can temporarily activate it by pressing `C-Spc` twice, then moving.  Note that the *region* is defined between last mark and point, whether highlighted or not, and you can push it to the kill ring with `M-w`.

For other tips, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657672/how-to-select-or-highlight-a-block-in-emacs).